# How to change language with shiny.i18n based on URL?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny.i18n

I have app in which I want to change language of app based on URL. I am using shiny.i18n package and JSON file from which I take words for translation.

This is JSON file. Take note that fr language is not French this is just for example.

```
{
  "languages": ["en", "fr"],
  "translation": [
    {
      "en": "Tab1",
      "fr": "This is tab 1"
    },
    {
      "en": "Tab2",
      "fr": "This is tab 2"
    },
    {
      "en": "My inputs",
      "fr": "This is my inputs"
    },
    {
      "en": "Cancel",
      "fr": "Cancel button"
    },
    {
      "en": "Subtab1",
      "fr": "This is subtab 1"
    },
    {
      "en": "Subtab2",
      "fr": "This is subtab 2"
    },
    {
      "en": "Title",
      "fr": "This is title"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is example of code

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shiny.i18n)

i18n <- Translator$new(translation_json_path='translate.json')
i18n$set_translation_language("en")

ui <- navbarPage(
  title = "Translation_test",
  position = "fixed-top",
  tabPanel(i18n$t("Tab1"),
           dashboardPage(
           options = list(sidebarExpandOnHover = TRUE), 
           
           dashboardHeader(disable = TRUE),
             dashboardSidebar(selectizeInput("input1",
                                               i18n$t("My inputs"),
                                               choices = c("Cylinders" = "cyl",
                                                           "Transmission" = "am",
                                                           "Gears" = "gear"),
                                             )
                              ), 
             dashboardBody(
               fluidRow(4),
               fluidRow(4),
               tabsetPanel(
               tabPanel(i18n$t("Subtab1"),plotOutput("plot"),
                        verbatimTextOutput("text"))
               )
               )
  )
  ) 
)


server <- function(input, output,session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(mtcars$wt, mtcars$mpg, main = i18n$t("Title"))
  })
  
  output$text <- renderText({
    isolate(session$clientData$url_hostname)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

I can change manually language in this line of code `i18n$set_translation_language("en")` but I want to change language based on URL. I get *session$clientData$url_hostname* and based on that I want to change language but it only managed to change *server* side of app and not *UI*.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shiny.i18n)

i18n <- Translator$new(translation_json_path='translate.json')

get_user <- function(session) {
  isolate(session$clientData$url_hostname)
}

i18n$set_translation_language("en")

ui <- navbarPage(
  title = "Translation_test",
  position = "fixed-top",
  tabPanel(i18n$t("Tab1"),
           dashboardPage(
             options = list(sidebarExpandOnHover = TRUE), 
             
             dashboardHeader(disable = TRUE),
             dashboardSidebar(selectizeInput("input1",
                                             i18n$t("My inputs"),
                                             choices = c("Cylinders" = "cyl",
                                                         "Transmission" = "am",
                                                         "Gears" = "gear"),
             )
             ), 
             dashboardBody(
               fluidRow(4),
               fluidRow(4),
               tabsetPanel(
                 tabPanel(i18n$t("Subtab1"),plotOutput("plot"),
                          verbatimTextOutput("text"))
               )
             )
           )
  ) 
)


server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  my_url_hostname <- isolate(as.character(get_user(session)))
  observe({
    if(my_url_hostname == "127.0.0.1"){
      i18n$set_translation_language("fr")
    }else{
      i18n$set_translation_language("en")
    }
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(mtcars$wt, mtcars$mpg, main = i18n$t("Title"))
  })
  
  output$text <- renderText({
    isolate(session$clientData$url_hostname)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This is visual representation of code above and as you can see difference between two pictures is only in title of plot and I want to change label of input and name of tabs.
[image]

Comment: I never used this package. But I would try to put the UI part in a `renderUI`, since this works in the server side.